# Replace several values in different columns at once - R

Tags: r

Please help! I am working with medication data which have a lot of misspellings. I am trying to replace **several values** (ex. "Orange", "orange", "ORANGE","Orangee") across **several columns** (about 50), all starting with "medication" and then followed by a number as our data is longitudinal so the same mistakes could be in 3 month column, 6 month column etc. At the moment I am using this

```
df$medication1[df$medication1 %in% c("Orange", "orange", "ORANGE","Orangee")] <- "Orange"
```

I have copied and pasted the same code and changed the column name each time but please please help me do this with a loop or something! We have 6 columns for every time point and 10 time points!

Comment: What are the column names? try `df %>% mutate(across(yourcols, ~ replace(.x, .x %in% c("Orange", "orange", "ORANGE","Orangee"), "Orange")))`

Comment: `sub("^(orange)e$", "\\1", tolower(df$medication1)` should work

Comment: @onyambu ... but that might also target other fruit names or strings.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `grepl` here with a regex pattern:

```r
df$medication1[grepl("(?i)^orangee?$", df$medication1)] <- "Orange"
```

Comment: You are  right!!

Comment: but that would only replace it in the column medication1, i have around 50 columns, will I have to code it for each individual column? Surely there is a better way to do this where I can specify all the columns I want this change to happen at once?

Comment: You can use dplyr's mutate_all or mutate_at to apply the same function to more than 1 column

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on previous answer:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble(
    medication1 = c("Orange", "orange", "ORANGE","Orangee"),
    medication2 = c("Orange", "orange", "ORANGE","Orangee"),
    medication3 = c("Orange", "orange", "ORANGE","Orangee"))

df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   medication1 medication2 medication3
#>   <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
#> 1 Orange      Orange      Orange     
#> 2 orange      orange      orange     
#> 3 ORANGE      ORANGE      ORANGE     
#> 4 Orangee     Orangee     Orangee

df %>% 
    mutate_all(.funs = ~ str_replace_all(.x, pattern = "(?i)^orangee?$", replacement = "Orange"))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   medication1 medication2 medication3
#>   <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
#> 1 Orange      Orange      Orange     
#> 2 Orange      Orange      Orange     
#> 3 Orange      Orange      Orange     
#> 4 Orange      Orange      Orange
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This applies the same replacement in each column.

EDIT:

To mutate only columns that start with the word medication, you could do the following:

```r
df %>% 
    mutate(across(
        starts_with("medication"), 
        ~ str_replace_all(.x, pattern = "(?i)^orangee?$", replacement = "Orange")
    ))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   medication1 medication2 medication3
#>   <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
#> 1 Orange      Orange      Orange     
#> 2 Orange      Orange      Orange     
#> 3 Orange      Orange      Orange     
#> 4 Orange      Orange      Orange
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you but in this case I would still have to manually write down all 50 columns. Is there a way to create a loop that takes all columns including the word "medication"

Comment: The mutate_all function would change all columns without having to list any names.

The "mutate_at" function or using mutate with the function across could select columns starting with a character string:
mutate(across(starts_with("medication"), ~ str_replace_all(...)))

Does that make sense?